# In Keras does merging auxiliary input preserve the sorting order

Tags: keras

In a model architecture which consists of the main data having convolutions applied to early levels followed by a concatenation (merge) followed by dense operations, can we rely on appropriate sorting in the concatenation when batches are shuffled?

As an example, consider a collection of photos each taken on a different day of the week. In the architecture first the photos will undergo convolution followed by a flatten operation. After flattening the single parameter day_of_week will be concatenated to the flattened tensor, and then dense operations lead to the final output.

My concern is that the association between the example photos and the day of week will be lost. Is this automatically taken care of the Model(inputs=[photoconvdata,dowdata],...) statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Td;lr** Yes, Otherwise multi inputs models would work for convolution.
Someone will probably be able to reference the code paths later in the answers, I'm going try to give some empirical evidence.

First let's simulate a 3D Tensor with (assuming you're using channels with your photos -- it dosent matter). We want to make it obvious that the 
indices of the examples are not touched. So we'll leave a bunch of zeros
in the last example (sample). And you'll notice that those same zeros are the last ones example output when we check the output.

The way we'll test it out is to build and fit a model. Afer each epoch 
we will check the output of the concatenation layer. What we should find some indication that the concatenation is happening at the right indexes.

```
from keras.model import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, concatenate, Flatten, Input
X = np.zeros((10, 10, 10, 10), dtype=np.int8)
# making the example different
X[:9, :] = np.random.randint(100, 110, (9, 10, 10, 10))

X_ this is your second input (photo_date)
X_ = np.ones((10, 1))

# model
inp = Input((10, 10, 10))
inp2 = Input((1,))
conv  = Conv2D(3, (2, 2))(inp)
flat = Flatten()(conv)
merge = concatenate([flat, inp2])
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merge)
model = Model(inputs = [inp, inp2], outputs=[out])

# here is the function we're going to use to checkout the output 
# at the concatenation layer
concat_output = K.function([model.inputs[0], model.inputs[1], 
                        K.learning_phase()], 
                       [model.layers[4].output])

# print the output before training. This is what we expect, 0's are
# in the last position with a 1 concatenated to every index.
concat_output([X, X_, 0])

>>>    [array([[ 113.494606,   54.331547, -290.99573 , ...,   53.661514,
         -289.99292 ,    1.      ],
        [ 114.72675 ,   51.808422, -284.84506 , ...,   48.507256,
         -286.96945 ,    1.      ],
        [ 110.17914 ,   54.97028 , -288.6585  , ...,   51.36793 ,
         -287.4386  ,    1.      ],
        ...,
        [ 111.09259 ,   57.093   , -281.43994 , ...,   49.77134 ,
         -288.38226 ,    1.      ],
        [ 108.35742 ,   45.220837, -284.50668 , ...,   48.4583  ,
         -295.17084 ,    1.      ],
        [   0.      ,    0.      ,    0.      , ...,    0.      ,
            0.      ,    1.      ]], dtype=float32)]
```

As expected. But this isnt your question, you're interested in what happens during batching. Lets batch and shuffle then. We'll look at the 
output of the Op after each epoch and while we can expect the output to be zero's (the weigthts of the models will change) we should see that all the values in the last example are the same.

```
# we train for 2 epoches using this was since we want to investigate 
the model output. after every round without having to deal
with callbacks.
for i in range(2): 
    print(concat_output([X, X_, 0]))
    model.fit([X, X_], y, batch_size=2) # shuffle = True by default

[array([[ 1.0643581e+01,  7.7266968e+01,  4.6593994e+01, ...,
         7.5334999e+01,  4.8712486e+01,  1.0000000e+00],
       [ 1.5145729e+01,  7.3742798e+01,  4.3532047e+01, ...,
         7.3937592e+01,  5.0245125e+01,  1.0000000e+00],
       [ 1.9058825e+01,  7.3847824e+01,  4.9182228e+01, ...,
         7.4079361e+01,  4.4511917e+01,  1.0000000e+00],
       ...,
       [ 1.1023483e+01,  7.0525513e+01,  4.0074528e+01, ...,
         7.4147705e+01,  4.4983501e+01,  1.0000000e+00],
       [ 1.1787775e+01,  7.6140900e+01,  4.5392090e+01, ...,
         7.5364082e+01,  4.5399754e+01,  1.0000000e+00],
       [-4.4723554e-03,  4.4722753e-03, -4.4723558e-03, ...,
         4.4722753e-03, -4.4723558e-03,  1.0000000e+00]], dtype=float32)]
Epoch 1/1
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.3998     
[array([[ 1.0641594e+01,  7.7268997e+01,  4.6592007e+01, ...,
         7.5337029e+01,  4.8710499e+01,  1.0000000e+00],
       [ 1.5143742e+01,  7.3744827e+01,  4.3530060e+01, ...,
         7.3939621e+01,  5.0243137e+01,  1.0000000e+00],
       [ 1.9056837e+01,  7.3849854e+01,  4.9180241e+01, ...,
         7.4081390e+01,  4.4509930e+01,  1.0000000e+00],
       ...,
       [ 1.1021496e+01,  7.0527542e+01,  4.0072540e+01, ...,
         7.4149734e+01,  4.4981514e+01,  1.0000000e+00],
       [ 1.1785788e+01,  7.6142929e+01,  4.5390102e+01, ...,
         7.5366112e+01,  4.5397766e+01,  1.0000000e+00],
       [-6.4606303e-03,  6.4977570e-03, -6.4600804e-03, ...,
         6.4977570e-03, -6.4600804e-03,  1.0000000e+00]], dtype=float32)]
Epoch 1/1
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.3995
```

Yep, notice that the values in the last index are all the same which serves as evidence that the last example are  still are transformed form
the 0's we input.

Hope this makes you confident that you won't be concatenating the photo times to the wrong image index.

Comment: Super detailed and careful answer, very helpful.